# JDBC display user information from MySQL DB

Tags: java, database, jsp, jdbc

I have come across another issue in reading / display user information. Once the INSERT is complete I have another submit button that should show the user his information (registration). Am I even heading in the right direction with this?

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*, java.util.*, javax.servlet.*, java.io.*, javax.servlet.http.*,     business.*"%>

<% 
Connection conn = null; 

try { 
    String email=request.getParameter("emailAddress");
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Users"; 
    String user = "root"; 
    String pwd = "password"; 
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 

    String query = ("SELECT * FROM User WHERE EmailAddress = '" +email+ "'");
    Class.forName(driver); 
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pwd); 
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
    User userObj;
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    statement.close();

    while(rs.next())
                   {
    userObj = new User(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5),     rs.getString(6));
    users.add(userObj);
           }
    Iterator it = users.iterator();
    User tempUser;

    while(it.hasNext())
                   {
        tempUser = (User) it.next();

        %>
        Username: <%= tempUser.getUserName() %><br>
        Password: <%= tempUser.getUserPass() %><br>
        First Name: <%= tempUser.getFirstName() %><br>
        Last Name: <%= tempUser.getLastName() %><br>
        Email: <%= tempUser.getEmailAddress() %><br>
        <%
    }

} catch( ClassNotFoundException e ){ 
    System.err.println( "Database Driver class not Found!" ); 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch( SQLException e ){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} finally { 
    try { 
        if ( conn != null ) { 
            conn.close(); 
        } 
    } catch ( SQLException e ) { 
        System.err.println( "Problems when closing connection" ); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 
%>
```

Comment: Does your homework require you to put all that Java code in the JSP? It's a bad practice. It should go in Java class.

Comment: Ya it does :(. From what I have read though it would be better to pass the information off to a servlet to do the db work.

Comment: **Edit** after checking, the select statement runs. I think the issue is with the while(rs.next())   ... hmmm

Comment: `String email=request.getParameter("emailAddress");`, have you checked whether the parameter value is coming correctly or not?

Answer (score 0):

You must close ResultSet too. You can use PreparedStatement instead of Statement to avoid SQL-injection.

Comment: rs.close();   lol. Ive been working on this project now for 18 hours.. I can hardly think, and this is the last thing I need to do. I just need the user info to display back lol.

Answer (score 0):

Writing java codes in jsp page is not good practice. Place your JDBC code to java beans. Here is the explanation of [JavaBeans components in jsp pages](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPBeans.html) from oracle (former sun).